# Why is Proto-Indo-European form for light *lewktom?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Why is Proto-Indo-European form for light *lewktom when Russian has satem лысина (lɨsʲɪnə) bald spot?

Comment: You should at least check Vasmer first. Although Derksen: *The comparison with Skt. rus̀ant- ‘shining, bright’ (Vasmer s.v.) does not seem
promising. A connection with \*lysto ‘shin, calf ’ (Lubotsky, p.c.) is semantically
feasible, cf. →*golěnъ vs. →*gòlъ.*

Comment: this question is really inte*rus̀ant*. Could *-сина* be akin to *shine*, \*(s)ḱeh₁y-, whence PSlav \*sijna or \*sъjna. Compare *Heiligenschein* "halo".

Answer (score 3):

The root **l-wk-* has dozens of descendants all across PIE, including Russian *luč*. Forms like that, Sanskrit *roka*, etc show clear evidence of a PIE velar **k*.

I'm not an expert on Slavic, but I'd assume *lysina* has `/s/` not from the satem shift but from some later development, possibly affected by the front vowel after it. (Alternately, it might come from a different root altogether, or be a borrowing, etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103269/discussion-on-answer-by-draconis-why-is-proto-indo-european-form-for-light-lewk).